# Forces acting on a person while bending

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

An obese person bends forward on the ground. The person's hand doesn't touch the ground, so will he accelerate forward?

Comment: I guess he will bend his legs at the same time to keep balance, no?

Comment: But he dosent fall

Comment: Resultant torque must be zero right?

Comment: Yes, indeed it must. And it is if all forces work through the Centre of mass. That is why he would bend his knees - to tilt a bit and move the Centre of mass. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bending brings the upper body in front of the rest, so the centre-of-mass is moved forward. Then the centre-of-mass is *not* directly above the point he stands on anymore (point where the normal force from the ground works). Gravity in centre-of-mass and this normal force from the ground are now both causing torques that do not cancel out but rather both make him start rotating and fall head-first forward.

Of course people are wired to keep balance. When bending the body, we bend in the knees to move some of the body backwards at the same time and maybe tilt the whole body a bit as well. All in order to keep the centre-of-mass exactly above the point of the normal force.

This is not about obesity but balance.